# A possible solution to the ODE $dy+(y\cot(x)-2\cos(x))dx=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following ODE
$$dy+(y\cot(x)-2\cos(x))dx=0$$
I found that its integrating factor is
$$\mu(x)=\exp\left(\int\cot(x)dx\right)=\sin(x)$$
and then the solution of the ODE
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\cot(x)y=2\cos(x)$$
will be
$$y(x)=-\frac{\cos(2x)}{2\sin(x)}+C\cdot\csc(x)$$
where $C\in\mathbb{R}$

I have to choose one alternative that is a *possible* solution to this equation:

1. $y=\cos(x)+C\sin(x)$
2. $y=\cos(x)+C\csc(x)$
3. $y=-\sin(x)+C\cos(x)$
4. $y=\sin(x)+C\csc(x)$
5. $y=\sin(x)+C\sec(x)$

but I couldn't rewrite the solution I found as one of these alternatives. Since
$$\cos(2x)=\cos^{2}(x)-\sin^{2}(x)$$
the best I could get was
$$y=-\frac{1}{2}\cot(x)\cos(x)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)+C\csc(x)$$

PS: the 4th alternative actually satisfies the ODE but I don't know how to rewrite my solution as it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using
$$ -\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin(x)}=-\frac{1-2\sin^2(x)}{2\sin(x)}=-\frac{1}{2\sin(x)}+\sin(x) $$
you will get the 4th one.